# Why Spring Data Jpa doing join on simple select?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have entity with @ManyToOne linking. When I do request like findByCity on it, spring data do "left outer join". But if I do it on hibernate with criteria eq - it get normal request like "select .... where city_id=...". 
How can I avoid join without @Query?

Comment: It's pretty much the same..;

Comment: Post some code and the generated SQL in both cases.

Comment: @VictorViola I see that with join is slower than without. why is it the same ??

Answer (score 0):

Per default a select which uses a `@ManyToOne` relation always uses join per definition. In Hibernate 5 Criteria you need to it explicit and create an alias for every join:
So instead of writing (Person -> Adress):

```java
session.createCriteria(Person.class).
  .add(Restrictions.eq("adress.serial", "42"));
```

we need to write

```java
session.createCriteria(Person.class).
  .createAlias("adress", "adr");
  .add(Restrictions.eq("adr.serial", "42"));
```

And createAlias seems to be not the perfect method name, because what is does is:

> Join an association, assigning an alias to the joined association.

But there is also a workaround, if you want to do a simple select a entity with a restriction to the **ManyToOne** relation by an **ID** **without a JOIN** (Neither in the *HQL* nor the resulting *SQL*).

Instead of using a join in the previous example, we can use the `adress_id`column:

```java
session.createCriteria(Person.class).
  .add(Restrictions.eq("adressId", "42"));
```

This works, if you specify an additional `adressId` field, which is only used as mapping info for Hibernate:

```java
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Person{
    @Id
    String id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "adress_id") 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Nullable
    public Adress adress;


    @Column(name = "adress_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String adressId;
}


@Entity
@Access(FIELD)
public class Adress{
    @Id
    String id;
}
```

The `AccessType.FIELD` is not needed (But we can leave getters/setters in example). The `FetchType.LAZY` and `@Nullable` are also optional, but make it clear when it makes sense to use it. We are able to load `Person` entities which have a specific `Address` (we know the address id). But we don't need a join because it's not needed for the WHERE-clause and not for the initial fetch (the address can be fetched lazy).